# How to set up the Brackets editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file

I want to use Brackets to view my HTML, JS, and CSS files I've written. However whenever I open a file from my folder "Code", Google Chrome Opens up an index of my desktop folders, then I have to click the folder "code" and go in the folder to click on it. How can I make it to where when I click on "live preview" Chrome loads the actual HTML file instead of traveling the world first?

```
Here is a picture of what's going on:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/03hEq.jpg

Comment: Sounds like a pain. Don't use brackets maybe?

Comment: Have you tried just dragging your project into the application icon?

Comment: yeah that doesnt work @sherrifderek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing your image, Julie/Desktop is your root.

So, here is what I would do.

Lets say Code2 is the folder that contains all your code for the site you are building. In this case, you would open Brackets and select file > open folder and then navigate to the Code2 folder and open it. This sets Code2 as the root directory for Brackets. Now, in that folder, make sure that you have an index.html file - preferrably the one that you are working on. Now clicking the view button should open the actual page in your browser.

If you dont have an index file, and want to load a different file then just toss a blank index file in the root, click the view button and a blank page should open in the browser. Now just change the path to include the proper name of your file and it should load the page you wish to edit. Saving should reload it in browser.

Example. If your index path is http://127.0.0.1:52497/index.html but you want to view a page with the filename of page2.html, then you would change the path to: http://127.0.0.1:52497/page2.html

Comment: ok so im going to just use my blank html template as the renamed file index.html and drag it on my desktop, open it up along with the html doc im working on and see if it works . Thanks!

Comment: Hey quick question- is there some type of plugin i have to use to make my javascript files funtion properly because when i add a transition effect to one of my images it goes straight to the next image without blending it...but when i run it in firefox and notepad ++ it works fine.

Comment: No. Native Javascript should run pretty much the same on all clients. Create a new question and provide the script you are using for your animation and we can review if there is a scripting issue.

Comment: So i actually just recorded my desktop to show what its doing @korgrue is there a way i can upload it here?

Comment: I do not believe so. You can upload it to a video host and provide the link though.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/hxsdcs91/5/ This is the i am using as well....I don't understand why thee "onmouseover" event does not function properly when i to fade the image in, when using brackets. It works perfectly fine in Notepad++ though. @Korgrue

Comment: Ahh, I get what you are asking now. Yes - this is a known issue with Brackets. 

Brackets uses a wrapper of sorts when it serves the page to your browser. Unfortunately, sometimes this wrapper causes some issues with interactive elements. You should never test your site functionality through the Bracket view in browser option. View in browser is only really intended for layout purposes.  To test your page functionality, you should be loading the html file directly into a browser window rather than running it through Brackets.

Comment: when you say "directly into" you mean like right clicking the file in my folder and then clicking  "open in chrome"? @Korgrue man this is unfair, I spent literally all night revising my code and i KNEW it wasn't an issue with what i had dude, like they should give me some new plugins for free or something, cause all that time i could've been starting some J Query tutorials hahaha. So would you recommend any additional plugins to solve this problem?

Comment: open the file in your file explorer and drag it into your open browser window rather than opening it trough Brackets (or right click - "open in chrome"). It wont auto reload on save, but you just need to click the refresh button after changes.

If you want to enable auto refreshing in the browser without using Brackets to do it - then I would recommmend installing the AutoReload plugin for Chrome. Follow the configuration steps closely.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Whatever directory you have imported into Brackets needs to have an index.html file. You dont have an index file in that root from what I can tell - so it has no idea what you want to load when you click the open in browser button.

Comment: so should i or can i take the sample one from the brackets sample folder? @korgrue

Comment: No. If you want to view the file you are working on by simply clicking the "view in browser" button - then your file needs to be named index.html and it needs to be in the root of the directory you have loaded into Brackets. Otherwise, you will have to install an autoreload plugin and load the page manually into your browser.

Comment: when you say root directory what directory are you referring to?